How to Integrate Payments for Sri Lanka in LKR Using Razorpay and PayPal?
I have a business based in India that sells products in Sri Lanka as well, and I'm using a single Shopify store for both. I integrated Razorpay for payment processing, and I need to support payments in LKR for Sri Lanka. Razorpay suggested adding PayPal for this, which I have done, but PayPal says it does not support INR or LKR, and the PayPal payments are still failing.
Should I add USD as the currency, or is there another way to accept payments in LKR? Shopify suggests using Shopify Payments, but it is not supported in India. How can I handle payments for both India (INR) and Sri Lanka (LKR) from the same Shopify store? Any advice on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Supported PayPal currencies are documented here. To process payments with PayPal your store must be configured in one of those currencies, such as USD.
If the PayPal payer has a funding source in a different currency, such as an LKR credit card, PayPal will do the conversion for that buyer at checkout time. Though an LKR funding source was used in such a case, you will not see this--all you will see is a successful PayPal payment in the listed/processing currency (e.g. USD).
